# Subqueries in Linq when attempting to get counts

Tags: linq, .net-core

I'm trying to get some subqueries to work in a call of mine. I am trying to make this call one trip to the database but cannot for the life of me solve how.  The query breaks on the GoodSections portion.  I have tried many different methods of doing this.  I keep getting this message:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Can someone help me?

```
var test = context.UserAssessments.Include(n => n.Assessment).Include(n => n.UserSections).ThenInclude(userSection => userSection.Section)
                .OrderBy(n => n.StartDateTime);

            MyAssessments = await test.Select(assessment => new MyAssessmentVM()
            {
                Assessment = assessment.Assessment.Name,
                CompletedDateTime = assessment.CompletedDateTime,
                StartedDateTime = assessment.StartDateTime,
                UserAssessmentID = assessment.ID,
                GoodSections = assessment.UserSections.Where(userSection => userSection.Section.SectionType != SectionTypeEnum.Reading)
                            .Count(n => n.Percentage < n.Section.ReadinessRangeHigh && n.Percentage > n.Section.ReadinessRangeLow)
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why are you separating the condition between the `Where` and the `Count`? I would place the whole condition inside the latter. Or maybe, have the condition inside the `Where`, and then `.ToList().Count()`?

Comment: I separated the where statement because I originally had it all in the where statement and it kept throwing errors. The only reason it is separated was me trying to test and figure out how to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
 GoodSections = assessment.UserSections
    .Where(userSection => userSection.Section.SectionType != SectionTypeEnum.Reading)

    // End of Where!

    .Count(n => n.Percentage < n.Section.ReadinessRangeHigh 
             && n.Percentage > n.Section.ReadinessRangeLow)
```

Apparently, every Assesment has a sequence of zero or more UserSections. It seems to me that every UserSection has a Percentage and exactly one Section.

You use Include to access the values of this Section, so I assume that Section is in a different table, with a one-to-many relation: every Section is the section of zero or more UserSections; every UserSection belongs to exaclty one Section, namely the one that the foreign key refers to.

First, try to simplify your Count, if that does not help, consider to GroupJoin.

```
GoodSections = assessment.UserSections
    .Where(userSection => userSection.Section.SectionType != SectionTypeEnum.Reading
                       && userSection.Percentage < userSection.Section.ReadinessRangeHigh 
                       && userSection.Percentage > userSection.Section.ReadinessRangeLow)
    .Count(),
```

Do the GroupJoin yourself:

```
var test = dbContext.UserAssessments.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.UserSections,

    userAssessment => userAssesment.Id      // from every Assessment take the primary key
    userSection => userSection.AssesmentId, // from every UserSection take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every UserAssesment, with all its UserSections
    // make one new
    (userAssessment, userSectionsOfThisAssessment) => new
    {
        UserAssessmentID = userAssessment.ID,
        StartedDateTime = userAssessment.StartDateTime,
        CompletedDateTime = userAssessment.CompletedDateTime,

        // To get the name, we need to get the Assesment that my foreign key refers to
        AssessmentName = dbContext.Assessments
             .Where(assessment => assessment.AssessmentId == userAssesment.Id)
             .Select(assessment => assessment.Name)
             .FirstOrDefault(),

        GoodSections = ... // TODO
    });
```

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that there is a oney-to-many relation between Sections and UserSections: every Section has zero or more UserSections; every UserSection belongs to exactly one Section, namely the Section that the foreign key refers to.

So for every userSectionOfThisAssessment we need to get the Section that the foreign key refers to: a standard inner join

```
GoodSections = userSectionsOfThisAssessment.Join(
    dbContext.Sections

    userSection => userSection.SectionId,    // take the foreign key to the section
    section => section.Id,                   // take the sections's primary key

    (userSection, section) => new
    {
        SectionType = section.SectionType,

        Percentage = userSection.Percentage,
        MaxPercentage = section.ReadinessRangeHigh,
        MinPercentage = section.ReadinessRangeLow,
    })
    .Where(joinResult => joinResult.SectionType != SectionTypeEnum.Reading
                      && joinResult.Percentage < MaxPercentage
                      && joinResult.Percentage > MinPercentage)
    .Count(),
```

For the GoodSections, we need to GroupJoin the `userSectionsOfThisAssessment` with all Sections. I'm not sure if this is a one-to-many relation, or a man

```
        MyAssessments = await test.Select(assessment => new MyAssessmentVM()
        {
            Assessment = assessment.Assessment.Name,
            CompletedDateTime = assessment.CompletedDateTime,
            StartedDateTime = assessment.StartDateTime,
            UserAssessmentID = assessment.ID,
            GoodSections = assessment.UserSections.Where(userSection => userSection.Section.SectionType != SectionTypeEnum.Reading)
                        .Count(n => n.Percentage < n.Section.ReadinessRangeHigh && n.Percentage > n.Section.ReadinessRangeLow)
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: All your assumptions are correct on this.  These are one to many relationships.  A section is a built out admin object, and a User Section is a record of someone completing that section.  So it could be null.  I'm looking through your code on this so sorry I haven't marked an answer yet, I'm trying to digest this.

Comment: Also, I separated the where statement because I originally had it all in the where statement and it kept throwing errors.  The only reason it is separated was me trying to test and figure out how to get it to work.